# Error while trying to display a dataset on Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a code that loads a dataset into  GUI using tkinter.
It now shows the following error on clicking the upload button.
Can someone point out what is the issue with my code...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\itsme\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\itsme\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandastable\core.py", line 320, in resized
    self.redrawVisible()
  File "C:\Users\itsme\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandastable\core.py", line 467, in redrawVisible
    self.drawText(row, col, text, align)
  File "C:\Users\itsme\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandastable\core.py", line 3298, in drawText
    tw,newlength = util.getTextLength(celltxt, w-pad, font=self.thefont)
  File "C:\Users\itsme\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandastable\util.py", line 47, in getTextLength
    t = scratch.create_text((0,0), text=text, font=font)
  File "C:\Users\itsme\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2810, in create_text
    return self._create('text', args, kw)
  File "C:\Users\itsme\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2776, in _create
    return self.tk.getint(self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\itsme\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\itsme\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandastable\headers.py", line 327, in handle_mouse_move
    if x > self.tablewidth+w:
AttributeError: 'ColumnHeader' object has no attribute 'tablewidth'
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\itsme\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\itsme\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandastable\core.py", line 154, in close
    util.SCRATCH.destroy()
  File "C:\Users\itsme\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2580, in destroy
    self.tk.call('destroy', self._w)
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "destroy" command: application has been destroyed
```

My code takes a dataset as input and displays it. Then it performs some operations and displays a particular part as a pie chart. While I have noticed the issue with the pie chart coding part, the readcsv method is causing some error. This code was working fine before. Some edit caused this error and I am unable to figure it out.

The code is:

```
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox as msg
from pandastable import Table
from tkintertable import TableCanvas
from easygui import *
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)



class csv_to_excel:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.file_name = ''
        self.f = Frame(self.root,
                       height = 200,
                       width = 400)
        self.f.pack()
        self.message_label = Label(self.f,
                                   text = 'COVID-19 INDUCED ANXIETY ANALYSIS',
                                   font = ('Arial', 16,'underline'),
                                   fg = 'Black')
        self.message_label2 = Label(self.f,
                                    text = 'DATASET ANALYSIS',
                                    font = ('Arial', 14,'underline'),
                                    fg = 'Green')
        
        self.convert_button = Button(self.f,
                                     text = 'UPLOAD',
                                     font = ('Arial', 14),
                                     bg = 'white',
                                     fg = 'Black',
                                     command = self.readcsv)
        self.clear_button = Button(self.f,
                                  text= 'CLEAR',
                                  font = ('Arial', 14),
                                  bg = 'white',
                                  fg = 'Black',
                                     command = self.clrscr)
        self.analysisbtn = Button(self.f,
                                  text= 'ANALYZE',
                                  font = ('Arial', 14),
                                  bg = 'white',
                                  fg = 'Black',
                                     command = self.analyze)
        self.reportbtn = Button(self.f,
                                  text= 'REPORT',
                                  font = ('Arial', 14),
                                  bg = 'white',
                                  fg = 'Black',
                                  command = self.plotr)
        
        
        self.exit_button = Button(self.f,
                                  text = 'EXIT',
                                  font = ('Arial', 14),
                                  bg = 'Red',
                                  fg = 'Black',
                                  command = root.destroy)
        self.message_label.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        self.message_label2.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        self.convert_button.grid(row = 3, column = 0,
                                 padx = 0, pady = 15)
        self.clear_button.grid(row = 3, column =1 , padx=0, pady= 15)
        self.analysisbtn.grid(row = 3, column = 2, padx=0, pady= 15)
        self.reportbtn.grid(row = 3, column = 4, padx=0, pady= 15)       
        self.exit_button.grid(row = 2, column = 3,
                              padx = 10, pady = 15)          
    
    def clrscr(self):
        self.f2.destroy()
        
    def readcsv(self):
        try:
            global v
            self.file_name = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = '/Desktop',
                                                            title = 'Select a CSV file',
                                                            filetypes = (('csv file','*.csv'),
                                                                      ('csv file','*.csv')))
            v=self.file_name
            df = pd.read_csv(self.file_name)
            
            if(len(df) == 0):
                msg.showinfo('No Rows Selected', 'CSV has no rows')
           
            else:
                self.f2 = Frame(self.root, height=200, width=300)
                self.f2.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
                self.table = Table(self.f2, dataframe=df,read_only=True)
                self.table.show()
                    
        except FileNotFoundError as e:
            msg.showerror('Error in opening file!', e)
            
    
            
    def analyze(self):
        
        #clean data: remove timestamp,remove null 
        data = pd.read_csv(v) 
        data.drop('Timestamp', inplace=True, axis=1)
        data = data.dropna(how='any')
        l=data.columns.values.tolist()
        #replace GAD7 response with equivalent values
        text = open(v, "r")
        text = ''.join([i for i in text]) 
        # search and replace the contents
        text = text.replace("Not at all", "0")
        text = text.replace("Several days", "1")
        text = text.replace("More than half the days", "2")
        text = text.replace("Nearly every day", "3")
        # output.csv is the output file opened in write mode
        x = open(v,"w")
        # all the replaced text is written in the output.csv file
        x.writelines(text)
        x.close()
        #list of domain values in the questionnaire
        dom={}
        for p in range(30):
            dom[p]=data[l[p]].tolist()
            dom[p]=list(set(dom[p]))
        #augmented dataset for increasing sampling size
        for j in range(10):
            q=[]
            for c in range(30):
                q.append(random.choice(dom[c]))
            data.loc[len(data)+1]=q
       
        data.to_csv('newd.csv',index=False)
        data=pd.read_csv("newd.csv")
        
        #obtain GAD7 scale results
        GAD = data['Feeling nervous, anxious, or on edge']+data['Not being able to stop or control worrying']+ data['Worrying too much about different things']+data['Trouble relaxing']+data['Being so restless that it\'s hard to sit still']+data['Becoming easily annoyed or irritable']+data['Feeling afraid as if something awful might happen']
        data['GAD'] = GAD
        gad = data["GAD"]
        cond_list = [gad<=4,gad<=9,gad<=14,gad>14]
        choice_list = ["Nil","Mild", "Moderate", "Severe"]
        data["Anxiety Level"] = np.select(cond_list, choice_list)   
                
        message = data.head()
        title = "Analysis"
        ok_btn_txt = "OK"
        output = msgbox(message, title, ok_btn_txt)
        print("User pressed : " + output)
    
    def plotr():
        
        k = pd.read_csv(file_name)
        window=Tk()
        f = Frame(window,
                       height = 200,
                       width = 300)
        frameChartsLT = Frame(window)
        frameChartsLT.pack()
        stockListExp = k['Anxiety Level']
        stockSplitExp = k['GAD']
  
        fig = Figure() # create a figure object
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111) # add an Axes to the figure
  
        ax.pie(stockSplitExp, labels=stockListExp,autopct='%0.2f%%', shadow=True,)
  
        chart1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,frameChartsLT)
        chart1.get_tk_widget().pack()
        window.mainloop()
        
        
     # setting the title  
       


       
      
                                    
            
root = Tk()
root.title('ANXIETY ANALYSIS')
obj = csv_to_excel(root)
root.geometry('800x600')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It looks like you have 3 errors right now. Try fixing them one by one. TIPS: `_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"` means that the canvas was destroyed, `_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "destroy" command: application has been destroyed` means you called `<Widget>.destroy()` twice on the same widget.

Comment: @TheLizzard thank you... The problem was resolved.